# Audio Capture in windows phone 8 with external microphone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, audio-recording, microphone, sample-rate

I can capture some audio in wp8.1 platform but the sample rate is very low: 16KHz. 
I'm trying now to connect an external microphone via the 3.5mm jacket but it not responding so much.... Is there an way at all to change the sample rate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: so I checked it and there is no way to do that. The SampleRate is fixed by the phone.

Comment: does this mean that there is no app that does it OR that no app recognizes external audio via TRRS?  a possibility is that the TRRS connector is not standard.  i will test my handsfree set.  if it works for phone app, there should be no reason why it couldnt be tapped into by other apps.